# VGA mode functionality in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting, vga, safe-mode

Basically why use VGA mode when you can use Windows 10 Safe mode, with the option of enabling networking? The only difference between Safe Mode and VGA ("enable low resolution") Mode as far as I can tell is the screen resolution (800 x 600 vs 640 x 480), and I read somewhere VGA mode has limited colors. Am I wrong or is there anything I missed?

Comment: "All customized start-up programs and scheduled tasks are disabled." for starters

Comment: @DavidPostill You are referring to Safe Mode right? I will add that since posting, I have found that Windows is apparently "fully functional" in VGA mode, whereas Safe Mode only runs certain drivers and does not perform certain system tasks. I guess this would mean that VGA is just normal Windows with the graphical resolution turned down and only basic color elements being displayed. Please, if I'm wrong correct me!

Comment: @MeesterMoo you are correct